# Problemas con codigo SQL en Python 3.7

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, flask, inyección-sql

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto donde tendre un respaldo de cierta informacion originalmente alojada en bases de lotus notes. Para backend estoy usando Flask en Python 3.7. Sin embargo, despues de revisar mi codigo con la herramienta AppScreener, esta dice que tengo vulnerabilidades que pueden ser aprovechadas para realizar una inyeccion SQL, por lo que no entiendo en donde puede estar el error.

El resultado que me arroja dicha herramienta es el siguiente:

```
for usuario in data:
print("Usuario", usuario)
  status = usuario['estatus_usuario']
  mail = usuario['email_usuario']
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Esta línea
    cursor.execute( "UPDATE administrador_usuarios SET estatus_usuario=%s
    WHERE email=%s;",(status,mail))

   conn.commit()
    conn.close()
  return json.dumps({"response":"ok"})
```

La sentencia que me marca como vulnerable es:

```
    cursor.execute( "UPDATE administrador_usuarios SET estatus_usuario=%s
    WHERE email=%s;",(status,mail))
```

pero no logro entender por qué. Cabe resaltar que soy nuevo en esto de las vulnerabilidades SQL.

De antemano gracias

Comment: Tal como la usas no es vulnerable. Sospecho que esa herramienta que usas se equivoca al interpretar la línea como si estuvieras construyendo la sentencia SQL a mano, usando el operador format `%`. Pero no es este el caso.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `%s` por el _placeholder_ `?` habitual de sqlite, con lo que seguramente deje de dar problemas AppScreener.